# Cookies don't get removed

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I do have a problem with my cookies: There is the `login.php` in the directory `/admin`. I use .htaccess for URL rewriting, so the user calls the login form by tiping in `domain.com/admin/login` and after a successfull login the user is able to surf in the admin area: `domain.com/admin/dashboard` (and so on). If the user wants to stay logged in permanently, the login file sets a cookie:

`setcookie('sid', $sid, time() + 3600, '/');`

So far, so good. But in the admin dashboard, there is a link to `domain.com/admin/logout` which calls up the file `logout.php` which is in the directory `/admin`, too.

The `logout.php` checks if the cookie is set and then tries to unset the cookie:

`setcookie('sid', '', time() - 3600, '/');`

I tried to set the expiration date in multiple ways so I don't think that this causes the problem. Then I tried to set the domain parameter. Because this should be a CMS for more than just one customer, I have to set a dynamic domain (I did this via `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`), but this did not work.

Has anyone an idea what I could do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're manually managing cookies instead of using PHP's `$_SESSION`? (Not saying that it's wrong to manually use cookies, but there's a perfectly good tools which already exists)

Comment: Have you tried making sure they're the same SESSHID? D a `document.cookie` in the browser to confirm the same `PHP SESSHID` and try `$_COOKIE['sid'] = null`

Comment: If the user loggs in he gets asked if he wants to stay logged in for a longer period of time. If he wants that he gets logged out when he closes the browser then $_SESSION['sid'] is used.
But as far as I know, it's not possible to use $_SESSION longer than the browser is opened.
So it's because of comfort reasons.

Comment: @PhilipTsang Yes, they do have the same. $_COOKIE['sid'] = NULL doesn't change (or delete) the cookie.